# Structure of a notification system

Tags: php, notifications, laravel, laravel-4

Hello im making a Movies and tv Show web page in laravel 4 where a user can follow a Tv show, i am storing the values at the user table for example:

```
user:jhon
password:secret
tvshow:1,2,7,3
```

Where the user it's following the tv shows with an id of 1 and 2 and 7 and 3 so the user its following 4 tvshows, not shure if it's best practice but i like it (if there is better practice please notify me).

I want to make a new notification system, where there are more than one type of notification:

```
| @this user mentioned you in a comment       |
|_____________________________________________|
| A new episode of #your_tv_show comes today  | 
|_____________________________________________|
| @user send you a message                    | 
|_____________________________________________|
| @user its following you                     |
\_____________________________________________/
```

I was thinking in something like:

Notifications table

```
|  id  |from_id | to_id |   type   |   read |
|  3   |    1   |   3   |  message |    0   |
```

But how will i get the notification link that it's like
http://www.mypage.com/username/meesage/3

And for example i have 300 users following #tvshow when y want to give a notification like a new episode of it i need to make 300 new records in the table.

the way i wanted the table just doesn't work, help please.

I hope you understand my problem, not much english.
If you need more info please ask and help with best practices.

Thanks

Comment: I'm certainly no expert but I think separating customer data from public data will help a lot. Could you not use a script that is fired client side once they're logged in to check for new notifications about the films they like. Like search through all films associated with this person then go and search the movies table/db for new notifications..?

Comment: I want an autoupdate every 5 seconds for a notification and that could have problems with the read or unread.

Comment: Having that aim is admirable, but on a site that I suppose will be very large it will be almost impossible without spending an arm and a leg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notification being a large table that gets 300+ messages, everytime a show sends an update is fine, as long as you keep it clean, by deleting 'seen' posts, once a week or whatever.

Theres no other way to really do a 'seen' message without attaching it to all the followers.

You could do a global message attached to the show, and then just send once to all followers, without the need for a message table, but then you wouldn't be able to do the whole 'seen' or 'unseen' bit.  Know what I mean?

But I would setup a table and model for the following of shows...
Call it Following or whatever....
Like so..

```
ID  |   user_id    |  show_id   | 
1          22            3
2          12            4  
3          22            12
```

Then you can just setup a relationship in your User model...and get rid of the whole comma delimitted thing, which could get really messy if the site grows large.

```
public function showsFollowing(){
   return $this->hasMany('Following', 'user_id');   
 }
```

And in your TV Show model...

```
 public function getFollowers(){
   return $this->hasMany('Following','show_id');
 }
```

This will allow you to get all the id's of which shows the users are following.
Or get all the ids of which users are following which shows...

Then you can use that data however you please.

Im 95% sure theres waaaay more elegant ways of doing this, Im just not up to the task of actually sitting down and planning a complete infrastructure :)

Also....for messages, you need to create a Message model, and then everytime you do anything in any of your controllers.....such as when someone follows or adds or deletes whatever....you create a new system message in your Message model.......

Heres an example if you have a user click the link www.yoursite.com/show/follow/2...
Then it add that show and user to the Following table, and send a message to user if the follow was succesful.

```
public function get_follow($id){

$follow = New Following;
$follow->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$follow->show_id = $id; //pass the show id 
$check = $follow->save();
  if($check){
   $message = New Message;
   $message->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
   $message->body = "You have followed ".Show::find($id)->showName;
   $message->seen = 0;
   $message->save();}

Return Redirect::back();

 }
```

Then whenever you have a message to send for a show, you do a batch send...
Not sure where you would do it....maybe you could have a controller, for uploading a new episode....to a show...and then everytime you do, it executes the message batch....Something along the lines of this......

```
public function post_uploadNewEpisode($id){
  //Obviously you would have input handling for file upload etc
  //But we're not covering that part here....just the message part.

  $show = Show::find($id);
  $message = "There is a new episode of ".$show->showName." available for download!";

 $followers = Followers::where('show_id','=',$id)->get();
 //Iterate over follower ids, and send a message to each...
 foreach($followers as $val){

  $message = New Message;
  $message->user_id = $val->user_id;   
  $message->body = $message;
  $message->seen = 0;
  $message->save();

}}
```

Completely untested code, and like I said before, Im very sure there are better ways to do this, but Im just thinking off the top of my head..

But Im sure from here, you can kinda get an idea of how to implement all this.
Good luck! :)

Comment: Ok thats a good idea but i think a type field in messagens table it's necesary to generate the link to the respective page of the message, i think i can get a basic notification system and add some things to it thanks